# Ploop vzctl compact ctid unable to reclaim

Tags: linux, openvz, ploop

I have tried using the scripts and also command *vzctl compact ctid* to reclaim the new free space for the vps with the ploop, but it do not extend the free space. I am getting following result:

```
Trying to find free extents bigger than 0 bytes
Waiting
Call FITRIM, for minlen=33554432
Call FITRIM, for minlen=16777216
Call FITRIM, for minlen=8388608
Call FITRIM, for minlen=4194304
Call FITRIM, for minlen=2097152
Call FITRIM, for minlen=1048576
0 clusters have been relocated
```

How can I reclaim the space for the files I have deleted within the server.

Comment: ploop uses 1MB blocks so even a single block (often 4k) used by the file system loaded by the container on it will keep 1MB in use.

Comment: I currently have 55GB of files on that file system. It was 113GB before from which I deleted 58GB. So just 55GB are in use now but still the ploop shows utilization of 113GB.

Comment: If any part of a 1MB block that ploop uses contains part of a file from your file system it can't be reclaimed. One option would be to defragment the file system with something like `e4defrag` (EXT4).